# Проблемы на странице заглушки аналитики сайта

Tags: дефект, локализация

Если у вас еще нет 25к репы, то на [странице аналитики сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) будет заглушка:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут надо бы использовать кавычки-ёлочки, а также вынести точку наружу.
В транзифексе полноценной строки не обнаружено, только отдельные части.

Завел смежный баг на MSE: [Move dot outside the quotes on site-analytics page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303973/339911)

Comment: сайт американский, поэтому в английском варианте точка имеет право внутри кавычек быть. «кавычки-ёлочки» в отличии от "обычных" или “smart quotes” не часто встречал в английском.

Comment: @jfs да, там уже ответили про такие приколы американского английского, но это не значит, что не стоит давать эту фразу переводить как того требуют локальные особенности на сайтах альтернативных языков.

Comment: серьёзный вопрос: что в моём комментарии могло создать впечатление, что не нужно точку за кавычки в русском переводе вынести? (а я ещё думал, что повторять "американский", "английский"*2 излишне в комментарии, но оказалось, что не достаточно)

Comment: @jfs комментарий? Я про разброс голосов на MSE. Сейчас там: +6/-3. Но это видимо из-за объединения нескольких ситуаций в одном вопросе.